# Limit pneumatic cylinder stroke

Tags: circuit-design

I have a solenoid operating pneumatic cylinder which is controlled by a timer. timer is fixed on a certain value (25s working followed by 60s rest) and as it starts to count stoke opens fully for 25s then retreats back. I want my cylinder to stop half way through its stroke so added a limit switch to cut the power of solenoid valve when triggered. The problem is that as soon as limit switch is released to normal position solenoid push the stroke to hit LS again till 25s is over. I need a circuit that breaks as soon as LS is triggered and remains that way until the timer restarts its counting again.

*Timing diagram for OP to edit.*

```
                     <-- 25 s-->
                      _________                    ________
Solenoid        _____|         |__________________|        |_________
                      _                            _
switch(desired) _____| |__________________________| |________
```

Comment: Can you post more information about your equipment? There are solutions, but the best one depends on your specific equipment.

Comment: I have a 2-port (2-way), 2-position pneumatic solenoid connected to cylinder in conventional way.

Comment: A mechanical solution (physically stopping the pneumatic cylinder) is likely to be preferable. Pneumatic cylinders usually work to end-of-travel; removing the air midway either allows the spring to return to the original position, or leaves them loose with no operating force.

Comment: 2-port, 2-way is not conventional as there is no way for the air to escape from the cylinder. For 2-way activation of a cylinder  4 or 5-port, 2-way would be a minimum unless you're using spring or gravity return. Your question is missing information on solenoid voltage and whether or not this is an industrial application. It seems you want to stop the cylinder at the limit switch for 25 s but you can't do that with a 2-way valve. You need 5-port, 3-way valve with either centre-open to relieve pressures or centre-closed to maintain pressures.

Comment: actually I need the stroke to retreat before 25s is over and not to extend till time loops again.

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your question then. I've added a timing diagram for you to edit. Note that your question is unclear. Please answer **all** the points raised in the comments.

Comment: Things we might like to know: Voltage on pneumatic control, active high or active low, limit switch type (n.o. or n.c. or both), can the system support an added relay or two, do you have access to the 24V or whatever the system voltage is or only the timer output to the solenoid?

Comment: Thank you for modifying the timing diagram. Unfortunately it seems that the limit switch turns on simultaneously with the solenoid (whereas it shouldn't turn on until until the SV has been on for long enough that the actuator reaches the switch). Then you're leaving the solenoid valve on so the actuator will continue out past the switch. You need to think this through a bit better. You haven't addressed all the points in the comments as requested.

Comment: I've seen hydraulic reservoirs used in-line with a pneumatic cylnders to avoid the compressability of air problems inheren it purely pneumatic drive.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser: solenoid is 220AC so is all other part of system.limit switch is NC. There is no restriction for adding other modules and parts

Comment: This might be fundamentally hard to do accurately just taking a pneumatic cylinder off the shelf. It's not like hydraulics, because the air is compressible, quite springy, and does not have much ability to hold in place except by pushing up against the wall at the ends of travel. You would need to add sufficient friction to make it stay still when stopped. Otherwise I agree with @Transistor's comment suggesting a 5/2 valve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWfHEc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am trying to understand: By hitting LS we energize the relay and break the circuit? so as soon as LS is unlatched circuit returns back to primary state!? problem not solved yet.

Comment: In this case, LS has to operate in normally open mode. When the timer energizes, the solenoid is operated as usual. When the LS is closed the relay latches, opening the air solenoid circuit and energizing itself to keep it latched until the power is removed by the timer turning off. At this point, the normal operating mode is returned and the timer is in the 60 second state.

Comment: @motioneye, the problem isn't solved yet because the problem isn't defined yet. If you're serious about getting an answer then you need to get serious about providing the information requested and doing a proper timing diagram. Don't dribble information through the comments. Put all the specification in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a control problem with very discrete states and well-defined transition between these states of operation.

That's what microcontrollers are for. Sounds like you buy one of the hundreds of cheap eval boards that come with examples (in C, or micropython or *shudders* even arduino) and writer 10 lines of code instead of designing complex timer boards.